# Jquery Mobile App keep app dimensions in desktop view

Tags: jquery-mobile

When I view my Jquery Mobile app on a tablet or desktop it resizes to fit.  Is there a way to force the tablet and desktop to keep the mobile dimensions and look like a mobile app on those screens?  Thanks Tom

Answer (score 0):

THe resizing is because some elements have size set to 100% in the CSS - overriding the style for `ui-mobile-viewport`, `body`, or `ui-page` should have the effect you are looking for.

Comment: I changed the % in ui-mobileviewport, and ui-page and it didn't change anything.  Could I use media queries and set the width and height there all the same for mobile, tablet and desktop?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd suggest inspecting it in chrome or firebug and checking which styles are actually applied. Some of the theme styles are more specific so would take precedence. You will need media queries once you get the desktop view working - you want to keep the percentage for mobiles as they generally have the same screen size but different resolutions.